# Electrolysis of Paramagnetic Ferric Chloride in Water

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm trying to settle a bit of a debate between a friend and myself over the cause of an effect observed when dissolving Ferric Chloride, Iron(III) Chloride (FeCl3), in water and supplying an electrical current.

Sticking a wire into either end of the container of solution causes the solution to form a line along the current path of a darker color. Neither of seem to be able to find a concrete explanation of what we  are observing, and can't seem to come to consensus as to whether this effect is caused by a Paramagnetic property of ions in solution or something else entirely.

I asked a similar question earlier which gained an answer that suggests Paramagnetism is at play, however I Distilled the question to iron particles suspended in solution which, I'm told, is completely different.

I'm curious now as to what causes this higher color concentration along the current passed through the solution and whether it can be observed in other ways or solutions. Can or does the same effect occur when subjecting an electrical current through any conductive solution?

If it's a Paramagnetic effect can one also observe diamagnetic effects in solution in a similar fashion?

Comment: Ferr**ous** Chloride is Iron (II) Chloride. Ferr**ic** Chloride is Iron(III) Chloride. Which did you mean?

Comment: @JohnRennie Ferric Chloride (FeCl3) is the compound under question. It's used to etch copper based circuit boards, my friend is an electrical engineer.

Comment: Is it possible the line is due material being dissolved from the electrodes?

Comment: Possibly, or even a secondary reaction taking place, but I don't think the change in color density is permanent. FeCl3 that has been spent, or used to etch a plate, changes color. But in this case, it isn't so much a color change as a color concentration, or this is how it appears.